# Using this.securejson = true;

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

If I put:

```
this.securejson = true;
```

into my Application.cfc, then my $.ajax function call doesn't callback a .done function.

It works if I turn securejson off.

Is there a known method to work with securejson in ajax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`This.SecureJson` only works with the built-in cfajax functionality - you need to disable it to work with any other libraries.

For more information, see [Pete Freitag's "Prefix Serialized JSON in ColdFusion"](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/720.cfm)

For a workaround, see [Chris.m0nk3y's "Disabling secureJson prefix at runtime"](http://chris.m0nk3y.net/blog/post/disabling-securejson-prefix-at-runtime) - where he suggests using `getPageContext().getFusionContext().setSecureJSON(boolean)` to toggle it on/off as required.